# Exported data file is blank

Tags: cognito-forms, export

I set up four forms and one receives hundreds of submissions. I have been wasting a lot of time copying and pasting the information from the form into an Excel document, because I was having difficulty exporting. Every time I try to export the data, I click on the file and the file is blank.

Can someone please help me with why I keep seeing blank information?

Answer (score 1):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  If you will file a support request (by logging into your account and then clicking on your name in the top right corner and selecting Support) then we can assist you in getting a good export of your data.